# GHCI -- Prompt colours not working on windows

Tags: haskell, cmd, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to set a custom prompt for GHCI on Windows, but the ANSI colours do not seem to be working.

I tried opening GHCI on CMD (and even in the new Windows Terminal app) and running

```
:set prompt "\ESC[101m\STX  \ESC[m\STX"
```

which should just display 2 red spaces, but the colouring does not work. It just shows two black spaces.

It works without any problem on my linux distro, so the code should be fine?
Also, it works on Git Bash but not on the VS Code terminal, even if I set it to use Git Bash by default.

I don't even know where to look for a solution, as it could be a GHCI problem or a CMD problem or I'm just missing some package that I need on Windows?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592]`

Comment: Running `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.4.3`

Comment: I tried ConEmu64, but that also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but it requires an extra `\n` after the prompt.
The following command shows it correctly.

```
:set prompt "\ESC[101m\STX  >\ESC[m\STX\n"
```

One Trick that can be applied is to use a combination of `\r` `\t` characters for a fixed tab width.

```
:set prompt "\ESC[101m\STX  >\ESC[m\STX\r\t"
```

I however could not find how to change the width of tab character in PowerShell or Windows Terminal.

Comment: adding a couple of \b (backspace) to the \r\t combo works for me!