# How to set colored GHCi prompt in Powershell

Tags: haskell, colors, prompt, ghci

I have searched the solutions online, and found some useful information as follows:

1. [Set ANSI Terminal Control enabled by default in Win10 according to **Glenn Slayden**'s answer.](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/320921)
2. Set the prompt in the configuration files `ghci.conf` according to [here](https://coderwall.com/p/13h9bw/colored-ghci-prompt-with-and-modules-on-separate-lines) and [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHCi_in_colour)

The following is my configuration:

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33mImported Modules: %s\n\ESC[34m\x03BB> \ESC[0m"
:set prompt-cont "\ESC[31m > \ESC[0m"
```

When loading `ghci`, it doesn't work (see the following screenshot)

[image]

It seems that only the first ASCII escape sequence `\ESC[33m` takes effect, and the remaining sequences are not rendered.

Next, I make the following changes according to [the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHCi_in_colour):

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXImported Modules: %s\n\ESC[34m\STX\x03BB> \ESC[0m\STX"
:set prompt-cont "\ESC[31m\STX > \ESC[0m\STX"
```

It's better, but still seems only the first escape sequence works and other sequences are ignored.

[image]

This time I guess that the rendering of escape sequences is probably related to the escape char `\n`, so I add `\n` at the end of each sequence and remove the `\STX` as follows:

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33mImported Modules: %s\n\ESC[34m\x03BB> \ESC[0m\n"
:set prompt-cont "\ESC[31m > \ESC[0m\n"
```

Now it works as expected, but has to introduce some extra `\n`, which causes ugly layout.

[image]

Now I have no ideas why it needs some extra `\n` to render the escape sequences correctly in the GHCi prompt and how to solve this problem.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: While I can't check it on Windows right now, one thing that might be worth trying is adding an extra `\ESC[0m\STX` to close the first escape sequence at the end of the first line. Your second attempt would then become `:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXImported Modules: %s\ESC[0m\STX\n\ESC[34m\STX\x03BB> \ESC[0m\STX"`.

Comment: @duplode I tried it, and the second escape sequence isn't rendered, which is not blue but the default white.

Comment: ANSI escape sequences will work correctly when [this issue](https://github.com/judah/haskeline/issues/130) in Haskeline is fixed. The people from the Unison language are working on it. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: Similar question over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/60142586/4709363 :
Looks like a workaround is: instead of a newline, use a carriage return, followed by a tab, and a number of backspaces:  eg. `:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STXImported Modules: %s\ESC[0m\STX\n\ESC[34m\STX\x03BB>\ESC[0m\STX\r\t\b\b\b\b\b"`